# Newly installed Python 3.9 can't find Jupyter notebook or other modules

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-3.9

I'm noticing that I have now installed Python 3.9 (it happened in the last 2 weeks, though I'm not exactly sure how) and now I can't run packages like Jupyter or Flask, which I used to be able to. I still have Python 3.7 installed as well. When I try to run them I get:

*-bash: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory*

I also tried reinstalling it but I still get the same error as above. Anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: Looks like python3.7 did get removed. Re-install Jupyter using Python 3.9 pip. `python3.9 -m pip install jupyter`

Comment: I’m not sure how I installed Python, it was a long time ago but probably brew? How did 3.9 appear in my computer is beyond me. I tried to install with python3.9 but it said the requirements were already met. Also, I'm noticing that at /usr/local/opt/python/bin/ I have 3 python folders: python3, python@3 and python@3.9. The strange thing is that the 3 of them have python 3.9 inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like some sort of corruption. Can you try this below?

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/jupyter'
brew install jupyter
brew link --overwrite jupyter
brew link --overwrite --dry-run jupyter
brew unlink jupyter && brew link jupyter
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly suggest you to use a virtual environment and install packages in there. Please stop installing packages in your system's python.

My recommendation would be using a package manager like miniconda, but you can simply use virtualenv and pip install your packages in there.

Comment: thanks, I should be doing that, you're right.